# Create Association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using `"sequelize": "^5.8.6"` and have created my project structure using `"sequelize-cli": "^5.4.0"`. I would like to create associations so that:

> One company has many ratings

I have created a `company` model, which looks like that:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    symbol: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.hasMany(models.Rating);
  };
  return Company;
};
```

My `Rating` model looks like that:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Rating = sequelize.define('Rating', {
    action: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Rating.associate = function(models) {
    Rating.belongsTo(models.Company);
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Rating;
};
```

My `Company` Migration look like the following:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Companies', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      symbol: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Companies');
  }
};
```

My `Rating` migration looks like the following:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Ratings', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      companyid: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Company',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      },
      action: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Ratings');
  }
};
```

When running, I get the following error:

```
> npx sequelize-cli db:migrate

ERROR: Can't create table `test_db`.`ratings` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What is the `models.Issuer` in your Rating model? Are you sure you should not have `Rating.belongsTo(models.Company);`?

Comment: @TheWildHealer Thx for your reply! Sorry that was a typo from my side. I corrected it in my above question. However, is there a way to see more about the error message?

Comment: Okay that's not the problem then. Have you tried specifying custom foreign/target/source keys? Shouldn't change anything but we never know.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't just left it out of your code, your company model association should read:

```
Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.hasMany(models.Rating, {
        foreignKey: 'companyid',
        targetKey: 'id'
    });   
};
```

And your rating model should read:

```
Rating.associate = function(models) {
     Rating.belongsTo(models.Company, {
     // associations can be defined here
         foreignKey: 'companyid',
         targetKey: 'id'
     });
};
```